# Proving that $\lim_{n \to \infty} (1+ \frac{i}{n})^n = e^i$

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

Prove that $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} (1+ \frac{i}{n})^n = e^i$

I was trying to proof in the same way of $\lim (1 + \frac{1}{n})^n = e$, but I couldn't proceed this way. Can someone give me a hint for this question?

Here we define $e = \sum_{k \in \mathbb N} \frac{1}{n!}$

Thank you

Comment: n is probably tending to infinity?

Comment: Yes, $n \to \infty$

Comment: How were you able to prove $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{1/n}=e$? The same "proof" works.

Comment: Is $i$ an imaginary unit here? Hint: substitute $m = \frac{n}{i}$, then $m \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$ and you can make use of your known limit for $e$. To be formal you have to tell us how you define $e$, because in most courses the limit which you provided is just a definition of $e$ etc.

Comment: Clayton, in this proof, I used that $ln (x^k) = k ln(x)$, but it doesn't work for complex logarithm

Comment: Don't write it in a comment, edit your question. Also specify if $i$ is an imaginary unit etc. Can you follow my hint?

Comment: @m_gnacik,  yes it worked, thank you!

Comment: @m_gnacik Your hint fails when $i$ is the imaginary unit.

Comment: To make my hint formal, you need to replace $n$ with $x$, in other words change limit of a sequence to an equivalent limit of a function. First I didn't notice that you meant $i$ to be an imaginary unit, I thought that it might be an arbitrary natural number. Having your initial limit with $n$ suggests that it is a limit of a sequence, and $n$ runs through natural numbers, and the $m$ substitution is not anymore a natural number so it needs to be formalised.

Comment: @Did , thanks for clarifying. I noticed that, I didn't notice compex-analysis subject and was editing the comment later after I realised what he meant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without too many details:

$|(1+i/n)^n| = (1 + \frac{1}{n^2})^{n/2}$

$\arg(1 + i/n)^n = n\tan^{-1} 1/n$

as $n \to \infty$, the modulus goes to $1$ and the argument goes to $1$. This is exactly $e^i$.